# Search string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c

The question is about searching name starting with letter 'G' in employees table. I am using Oracle 12c Version.

I came across the answer:

```
select * 
from employees 
where first_name >= 'G' 
  and first_name < 'H';
```

Could you please help me to understand the logic behind this.

Comment: they're just string comparisons, which means `'g' < 'harrison'` is TRUE, because `g` comes before `h` in the alphabet. the length of the strings is irrelevant. the characters are compared in lock step, as soon as there's s mismatch, you get the comparison results.

Answer (score 2):

Other than what is being commented, you can as well use `LIKE` operator since you are eventually trying to get all `first_name` starting with `G`

```
select * from employees where first_name like 'G%'
```

Comment: Thanks Marc & Rahul

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp as well to search your names starting with G as below:

```
select * from employees 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (first_name, '^G','i');
```

here parameter 'i' will ignore the case of the name.